# Convert docx to doc using Apache POI, TIKA

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, doc, apache-tika

Is it possible to convert docx file generated from apache poi to doc ?
I'm generating docx files from customs templates, but sometimes I need to convert it to doc ? Is it possible to do it with apache tika or poi ?

Comment: Question is: what have you really tried?

Comment: I looked for solutions in this libraries, but I didn't find any solution. I'm looking only for hint is it possible or what use to achieve